# Problem installing Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed MS Ajax Control Toolkit in Visual Studio 2010.

I can see all the Web Controls under ToolBox in TAB Ajax Control Toolkit.

BUT in the moment of dragging (using) a control, example HTML Editor onto a page, nothing happen, no error, no markup added to code.... and I cannot use it!

So what I am doing wrong?

I installed in a directory called

C:\VisualStudio-Tools\AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Although i have no clue what might be the problem, a common cause of issues which result in 'nothing happens' is 'write permissions on disc fail'. Maybe do a 'FileMon/ProcMon' run while trying perform the actions that fail and see if there's any file related issue you can find.  

Hope this helps,

Comment: hello, what do your mean for 'FileMon/ProcMon? maybe some permission setting could be the reason. in my case i follow this article http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx but in step 2 I COULD NOT FIND the UNBLOCK BUTTON.. could be this one the problem?

Comment: Having had a quick look at the documentation page you described, i would doubt it's that "unblock" action. This seems to be a step required for "unpacking", which according to the 'availability of the toolbox items' was successfull.

My next guesses (and guesses they are) would be:
- You are missing 'other' libraries which are required/expected by the Ajax Control Toolkit. (a certain MS Ajax base set?)
- The Toolkit is not compatible with Visual Studio 2010, but VS 2008.

Comment: ProcMon/FileMon are tools which allow you to see what your computer is doing (in processes, thread, what registry keys are being read/written, etc. etc.). They are low level debugging tools and can be found on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Thanks Marvin for you insight on it

Answer (score 2):

It may be the framework version you are developing in. I had a similar problem where I was working in .NET 3.5 but had downloaded and added AJAX toolkit 4 to my toolbox. I could see the controls but they were greyed out and unusable.

I downloaded and installed AJAX toolkit 3.5 ([download here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475#DownloadId=116533s)) and it has solved my problem. The controls work beautifully!